# objective c linux compile script

Tags: objective-c, linux, compilation

Im new to scripting,
done some basic scripts, but wonder how can I create a script that I could call and say the name of the file to compile in objective c in linux

ie

> $ gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` -lgnustep-base hello.m -o hello

so instead of all that long line I could use

> $compile hello.m

to become the above line?
hope this makes sense!
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to learn how to use [GNU Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/), and [write a makefile](http://www.google.com/search?q=makefile+tutorial).